# Сборка XSD с помощью CMake External Project

Tags: ssl, cmake, xsd

Решил попробовать собрать проект и зависимости (xerces, xsd) с помощью CMake External Project. Сижу за прокси, которая прописана в среду Ubuntu 18.10 (http_proxy и пр.). Текущая версия CMakeLists (пока в сборку xsd не добавлена зависимость от xerces):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12.1)
project(proj LANGUAGES CXX)

# Enable ExternalProject CMake module
include(ExternalProject)

# Download and build Xerces
ExternalProject_Add(
    xerces
    URL http://www.apache.org/dist/xerces/c/3/sources/xerces-c-3.2.2.tar.gz
    URL_HASH SHA256=dd6191f8aa256d3b4686b64b0544eea2b450d98b4254996ffdfe630e0c610413
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    PATCH_COMMAND ""

    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/xerces

    CMAKE_ARGS
        -Dthreads:BOOL=OFF
        -Dnetwork:BOOL=OFF
        -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
        -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE="-O2"
        -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="-O2"
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/xerces

    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}

    # Disable install step
    #INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

# Download and build XSD
ExternalProject_Add(
    xsd
    URL https://www.codesynthesis.com/download/xsd/4.0/xsd-4.0.0+dep.tar.bz2
    URL_HASH SHA1=ad3de699eb140e747a0a214462d95fc81a21b494
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    PATCH_COMMAND ""

    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/xsd

    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/xsd

    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}
        -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}

    # Disable install step
    #INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

Xerces корректно загружается и собирается. Проблема состоит в том, что xsd отказывается загружаться. Получаю лог:

```
 error: downloading 'https://www.codesynthesis.com/download/xsd/4.0/xsd-4.0.0+dep.tar.bz2' failed
     status_code: 35
     status_string: "SSL connect error"
     log:
     --- LOG BEGIN ---
     Uses proxy env variable https_proxy == 'https://10.2.2.161:3128/'
Trying 10.2.2.161...

  TCP_NODELAY set

  Connected to 10.2.2.161 (10.2.2.161) port 3128 (#0)

  ALPN, offering http/1.1

  successfully set certificate verify locations:

    CAfile: none
    CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

  [5 bytes data]

  TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):

  [512 bytes data]

  [5 bytes data]

  error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

  Closing connection 0
```

Гугление ошибки `error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number` привело к выводу о том, что www.codesynthesis.com или моя машина не поддерживают SSL/TLS какой-то версии.

При этом команда `curl https://www.codesynthesis.com/download/xsd/4.0/xsd-4.0.0+dep.tar.bz2 -o xsd.tar.bz2` отрабатывает корректно. Пытался разобраться, как работает External Project - он выполняет file(DOWNLOAD), но как и с помощью чего происходит загрузка - не указано.

Подскажите, как обойти подобную проблему?

Comment: В [исходниках CMake](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/third_party/cmake) нашел опции сборки - по умолчанию происходит сборка со своей версией curl (--no-system-curl), т.е. в CMake есть своя версия curl. Пока не смог понять, как определить версию используемого curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На другой машине сборка происходит без проблем, закрываю вопрос.